# Django: filter queryset by field of not related model

Tags: django

I have models without relations:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a_id = models.IntegerField()
```

How to filter queryset of `A` objects if there is `B` object and `A().id == B().a_id`?

It's easy to do with ForeignKey (`A.objects.filter(b__isnull=False)`), but how to do it without relation?

Update: will be great to do it with single request.

Answer (score 3):

```
ids = B.objects.values_list('a_id', flat=True)
A.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

Comment: is not this result in loading the `ids` into the memory? I believe this can be optimized by doing  the containment check at the db level.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb  Yes, it does. Maybe it can be done in 1 fewer query but I don’t know how to do that with Django ORM. If you know how, you should post another answer..